# SQL insert, What do all these characters do in this insert statement defing values? "&""&"'"&N4&"', "&""&"'"&"Mapping"&"',

Tags: sql, syntax, insert

What do all these characters do in this insert statement defining values?

```
"&""&"'"&N4&"',"&""&"'"&"Mapping"&"',
```

I am trying to understand what each one does? I know N4 is a cell location and Mapping is a hard coded value. It works but, what going on here?

Complete command:

```
"insert into partnerrules (name,description,[default],version,doc,[order],active,isComboBox) values("&"'"&P3&"',"&""&"'"&M3&"',"&""&"'"&N3&"',"&""&"'"&"Mapping"&"',"&""&"'"&"856"&"', "&""&"'"&O3&"',"&""&"'"&"1"&"',"&""&"'"&"0"&"'"&")"
```

Comment: That has nothing do do with SQL,but with the programming language you are using (looks like Visual Basic)

Comment: @DRapp covers this pretty well. I'd just also like to point out though that much of that complete command can just be eliminated. For example, `","&""&"'"&"856"&"',"` can simply be replaced with: `",'856',"`. Much of the string similarly reduces.

Comment: Tom H, Thanks for the info, I have it down to this now.                                                                                                 ="insert into partnerrules (name,description,[default],version,doc,[order],active,isComboBox) values('"&P3&"','"&M3&"','"&N3&"','Mapping','856','"&O3&"','"&"1"&"','0')"  Works great, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the code, it appears to be done in VB and the "&" character is used to add strings together such as

```
someVar = "hello " & "world"
```

would result in

```
"hello world"
```

So, what is attempting to be done is adding the value of strings and quotes around them to build out a sql-insert statement.  However, it is poorly done as you are open to sql-injection being done this format but parameterizing instead.  Do some research on it as there is not enough to adequately respond without more actual source code to show context.

```
complete command: ="insert into partnerrules (name,description,[default],version,doc,[order],active,isComboBox) values("&"'"&P3&"',"&""&"'"&M3&"',"&""&"'"&N3&"',"&""&"'"&"Mapping"&"',"&""&"'"&"856"&"', "&""&"'"&O3&"',"&""&"'"&"1"&"',"&""&"'"&"0"&"'"&")"
```

would result in the following
ex: if the following variables have the following values

```
P3 = "test1"
M3 = "test2"
N3 = "test3"
O3 = "test4"
```

I am doing explicit line breaks for readability vs too long on one line...

```
    insert into partnerrules (name,description,[default],version,doc,[order],active,isComboBox) values (
```

now, the area of all your quotes and &

```
 'test','test2','test3','Mapping','856','test4','1','0')
```

What SHOULD have been done is something more the along the line of... the underscore is continuation line in VB

```
DIM OleDbCommand myInsert = new OleDbCommand( "", YourConnection )
myInsert.CommandText = "insert into partnerrules ( name, description, " _
   & "[default], version, doc, [order], active, isComboBox ) " _
   & " values ( ?, ?, ?, 'Mapping', '856', ?, '1','0')
```

In this case, the "?" characters represent PARAMETER PLACE-HOLDERS for what you want to actually insert into the table.  Then, add your parameters in the same order as they would be representative of.

```
myInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmForName", P3 )
myInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmForDescription", M3 )
myInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmForDefault", N3 )
myInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmForOrder", O3 )
```

Unsure of data types due to limited content provided.

Comment: I think that "Mapping" is actually a hard-coded string.

Comment: @TomH, thanks, and adjusted accordingly... really bad with over-quoted string